# Is "le" redundant in "El gobernador 'le' extendió el perdón al prisionero"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

The sentence in question is the following:

> El gobernador **le** extendió el perdón al prisionero.

The word 'le' seems redundant to me. I know it means (to) him. Is not the object specified directly (al prisionero)? Will the sentence be still correct if we remove 'le'?

Comment: You are right, _le_ here is wrong since the indirect object is also stated in the sentence. Some good readings on how this could be valid: [Duplicación de los complementos directo e indirecto](http://lengua.laguia2000.com/sintaxis/duplicacion-de-los-complementos-directo-e-indirecto), [Reduplicación del complemento en posición preverbal](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Pronombre%20cl%C3%ADtico%20reduplicativo.htm) and from RAE: [Pronombres personales átonos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF).

Comment: @fedorqui it's not 'wrong', it's optional. And it's usual to include it in oral speech. See 5.2.a in the RAE article you linked.

Comment: I know it's not directly related to the question, but I've never heard the verb "extender" in that context. It's true that a possible meaning of that verb is to write down something official, but one do not write the "perdón"(don't know how to say it in english in this context, forgiveness?), one do write the document where the "forgiveness" is officially reflected. So if I want to use the verb "extender" I'd use "certificado de perdón" or whatever the legal name of that document, in other case I wouldn't use that verb, for example: "El gobernador dió el perdón" or "El gobernador perdonó".

Comment: @Nox _perdon_ = pardon in English

Comment: @rsanchez very good catch! Thanks. To me it did sound a bit bad and I did not read all the article throughly enough to find this case.

Answer (score 2):

Greatings from Spain, Fire758.

If 'le' is redundant or not depends on the context. In formal registry, we told

> El gobernador extendió el perdón al prisionero.

Because we don't want to emphasize the figure who performs the verbal action. If you want to emphasize the person, you can use 'le'.

Have a good day!

Comment: In other words, the redundance is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: Note that the *le* is optional if and only if the explicit object (*prisioneto*) is *not* a personal pronoun. If it is, the duplication is mandatory (*le extendió ... a él* or *me extendió ... a mí*). In such a case, the optional element is the explicit reference (you can say *me extendió* or *me extendió a mí* but not *extendió a mí*)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :))) I am still a novice so I am not very good at catching such subtleties

Comment: @guifa - Would you write an answer when you have a chance, or propose a duplicate?